# Device-Specific @media queries don't seem to work

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

#### Hello everyone

I'm using a 'main' media query to target all major changes form desktop to mobile with this (scss) :

```
// media breakpoint variables
$mob-exslim: 320px;
$mob-slim: 360px;
$mob-regular: 375px;
$mob-medium: 390px;
$mob-plus: 414px;
$mob-large: 428px;

@media screen and (min-width: $mob-exslim) and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .contact-indicator {
    display: none;
  }
  .hero-wrap {
    margin-top: 70px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    // disable left side of the hero
    .left-side {
      display: none;
      .main-img {
        display: none;
      }
      .hero-arrow {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    // disable the right side of the hero
    .right-side {
      display: none;
      .main-heading {
        display: none;
      }
      .hero-descrip {
        display: none;
      }
      .button-wrap {
        display: none;
        .hero-btn {
          display: none;
        }
        .btn-arrow {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    }
    .mobile-title {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      .flex-left {
        min-width: 100vw;
        width: 100vw;
        max-width: 100vw;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: flex-end;
        .mobile-h2 {
          position: absolute;
          right: 19px;
          font-size: 33px;
          font-weight: 300;
          text-align: right;
          max-width: 298px;
          width: 298px;
          min-width: 298px;
          margin: 8px 0 0 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        .mobile-hero-img {
          max-width: 355px;
          margin-right: -140px;
        }
      }
      .mobile-hero-p {
        margin-left: -45px;
        font-size: 15.5px;
        margin-top: 55px;
        max-width: 272px;
        line-height: 26px;
      }
      .mobile-hero-btn {
        margin-top: 45px;
        min-width: 191px;
        max-width: 191px;
        min-height: 53px;
        height: 53px;
        max-height: 53px;
        border-radius: 14.5px;
        background-color: $grid-black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then, when I'm trying to be more specific with the viewports like this:

```
// 375PX WIDTH & 667PX HEIGHT -- iPHONE 6,7,8
@media screen and (min-width: $mob-regular) and (max-width: 389px),
  screen and (min-height: 667px) and (max-height: 667px) {
  .hero-wrap {
    margin-top: 65px;
  }
  .mobile-title {
    .mobile-hero-p {
      margin-top: 40px;
    }
  }
}


// 375PX WIDTH & 812PX HEIGHT -- iPHONE X, XS, 11 PRO
@media screen and (min-width: $mob-regular) and (max-width: 389px),
  screen and (max-height: 812px) {
  .mobile-title {
    .mobile-hero-p {
      margin-top: 70px;
    }
  }
}
```

The last two media queries don't seem to get registered.

If it helps, all the code is available on github : https://github.com/DesignedByNino/gridbase-studio in the 'src' folder under 'css/index.scss'.
This project uses vue.js - but it's not exactly relevant to the question, just so you know if you take a look.

Thank you in advance for all the answers!

Comment: You are missing a `}` at the end of the first code snippet provided by you.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal thank you pointing it out mate, but unfortunately that's just missing from me copy pasting it from vs code to this website, the actual code base includes that '}' last bracket.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal you can take a look at the whole project, I have it hosted on github, there's a link in the question's description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time in Chrome Dev Tools, I found out that the styles I was trying to target with the device specific media queries were not registering because I was not specific enough in SCSS with the last media queries.

Answer (score 0):

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)

> A typical mobile-optimized site contains something like the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

> The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to
> a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value
> device-width, which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a
> scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height
> values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size
> or position based on the viewport height.)
>
> The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is
> first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and user-scalable
> properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

and then you can use your media queries:

```
@media (min-height: 768px) and (max-height: 768px) 
     and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1366px) {

}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've created a simplified sample:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1020px)
  and (min-height: 813px)
{
  .mobile-title {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 389px),
  screen and (min-height: 0px) and (max-height: 667px) {
    .mobile-title {
      background-color: lightpink;
    }
}



@media screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 389px),
  screen and (min-height: 668px) and (max-height: 812px) {
    .mobile-title {
      background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class="mobile-title">
    A title
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the ` meta ` tag is already present and working properly, the first media query works just fine, it's when I try to implement the other more specific ones that it's not getting registered. Weird enough as css works from top to bottom so the last rulesets should override the top one in the first media query.

Comment: @NinoP please, see my updated answer. I've created a simplified example and checked with different devices. You can adjust it to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks again for the interest @StepUp, but unfortunately it doesn't work in my project. What I am trying to do is to adjust the top margin of 2 elements, a paragraph and a div parent element based on the device height (given that an iPhone X has a taller display - height: 812px - than an iPhone 6,7,8,- height: 667px - yet it has the same viewport width of 375px) so that the main CTA button still shows up above the website fold.